# awk compute average, but only for specific values in certain columns

Tags: awk, average

I have a csv file with 6 columns and 1M rows. The sample file is like this:

```
19;19;2021-06-01;0;France;10.3991
19;19;2021-06-01;0;Germany;0
19;19;2021-06-01;0;Others;8.08681
19;19;2021-06-01;0;Portugal;2486.39
19;19;2021-06-01;0;Spain;7.70791
19;19;2021-06-01;2;Switzerland;5.3688
19;19;2021-06-01;2;United Kingdom;0.00256085
19;19;2021-06-01;2;France;13.4166
19;19;2021-06-01;4;Germany;0
```

All the columns can have different values (for example, the first and second columns can have values such as "19", "20", "21", .. and so on. The third column goes from 2021-06-01 to 2021-06-29. Fourth column can have "2", "4", "6", ...up to "22". Fifth column can have different nationalities).

I need to compute the average of the 6th column based on the values from the days "2021-06-02", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-16" and "2021-06-16", and assign it to the day "2021-06-30".

But some values in some columns are not present in all the days.

In other words, I need to check if the values of the columns 1,2,4,5 are the same for these different days, then compute the average of column 6 for this four days.

For example:

```
19;19;2021-06-02;0;France;Value1
19;19;2021-06-09;0;France;Value2
19;19;2021-06-16;0;France;Value3
19;19;2021-06-23;0;France;Value4
```

Then, `Averagevalue=(Value1+Value2+Value3+Value4)/4`

With this, I can assign the average value as:

```
19;19;2021-06-30;0;France;Averagevalue
```

Next,

```
19;19;2021-06-02;2;France;Value1
19;19;2021-06-09;2;France;Value2
19;19;2021-06-23;2;France;Value3
```

Then, `Averagevalue=(Value1+Value2+Value3)/3`

With this, I can assign the average value as:

```
19;19;2021-06-30;2;France;Averagevalue
```

And repeat this procedure for all the possible values of the columns 1,2,4 and 5.

I tried this:

```
awk -F";" '{if($3=="2021-06-02"||$3=="2021-06-09"||$3=="2021-06-16"||$3=="2021-06-23") seen[$1";"$2";"$4";"$5]+=$6 count[$1";"$2";"$4";"$5]++} END { for (i in seen) print i, seen[i]/count[i] }' input.csv
```

without success. Any ideas?

Comment: what if the input already has a line with `2021-06-30`? will the first 2 column values always be the same for all days for a given country (eg, 19 & 19 for France) ... if not, please update the question to expand on you sample inputs and the associated result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem with two passes of awk:

```
awk -F";" '{if($3=="2021-06-02"||$3=="2021-06-09"||$3=="2021-06-16"||$3=="2021-06-23") print $1";"$2";"$4";"$5";"$6}' june2021-no30.csv > 4dnd

awk -F";" '{s[$1";"$2";"$3";"$4]+=$5 c[$1";"$2";"$3";"$4]++ } END { for (i in s) print i";"s[i]/c[i]";20210630" }' 4dnd > 4dave
```

Then, with sort and some reformatting I got the file I needed

Answer (score 1):

Let's correct your example to having consistent `;` used as a delimiter.

Given a file like so:

```
$ cat file
19;19;2021-06-01;0;France;10.3991
19;19;2021-06-01;0;Germany;0
19;19;2021-06-01;0;Others;8.08681
19;19;2021-06-01;0;Portugal;2486.39
19;19;2021-06-01;0;Spain;7.70791
19;19;2021-06-01;2;Switzerland;5.3688
19;19;2021-06-01;2;United Kingdom;0.00256085
19;19;2021-06-01;2;France;13.4166
19;19;2021-06-01;4;Germany;0
19;19;2021-06-02;0;France;1
19;19;2021-06-09;0;France;2
19;19;2021-06-16;0;France;3
19;19;2021-06-23;0;France;4
19;19;2021-06-24;0;France;5
19;19;2021-06-25;0;France;6
19;19;2021-06-26;0;France;7
```

Since you seem to have [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date stamps, you can filter a date *range* with string comparisons:

```
$ awk -F ";" '$3>="2021-06-02" && $3<="2021-06-23"' file
19;19;2021-06-02;0;France;1
19;19;2021-06-09;0;France;2
19;19;2021-06-16;0;France;3
19;19;2021-06-23;0;France;4
```

Or, if you only want those specific four dates you can create an array of the dates of interest like so:

```
awk -F ";" -v dates="2021-06-02;2021-06-09;2021-06-16;2021-06-23" '
BEGIN{split(dates,a,";"); for (e in a) datesa[a[e]]}
$3 in datesa' file
# same output
```

Now you can calculate a running average on what you filter:

```
awk -F ";" '$3>="2021-06-02" && $3<="2021-06-23"{
    sum+=$6; cnt++; r=sprintf("%s,%s,2021-06-30,%s,%s,%s",$1,$2,$4,$5,sum/cnt)
}
END{print r}' file
```

Prints:

```
19,19,2021-06-30,0,France,2.5
```

Note: This does not filter based on `$5` the country or do anything but take the last value for the other fields in the example since this was not specified.

Comment: many thanks for your help! I didn't check your procedure because I already found a solution

Answer (score 1):

Filterring in awk should be done outside the `{}`

Filtering on the needed dates can be done using this code:

```
$3~"2021-06-" && substring($3,length($3)-1)%7==2
```

The mod-operator (`%`) calculates the remainder after integer division, so in this case returns all Wednesdays in June 2021 (including the 30th)

So, your first line could have looked like:

```
awk -F";" '$3~/2021-06-[012]/ && substring($3,length($3)-1)%7==2{ print $1";"$2";"$4";"$5";"$6}' june2021-no30.csv > 4dnd
```

Where `$3~/2021-06-[012]/` is matching all the dates in June 2021 from the 1st until (and including) the 29th.

The second part `substring($3,length($3)-1)%7==2` takes care of filtering the Wednesdays (2,9,16,23)